# Scanning through text to find left and right characters

Tags: java, substring, bufferedreader, charat

I must scan through this:

JD IR BW TQ DW SH UB XW AH NG AS XW CH UF BW FO DW SH UB BW TQ GW UH YG JV IE VM YE JD UO

Then match up the right and left letter of each character with the corresponding character in this text:

MONCLETABDFGHIJKPQRSUVWXYZ

So in the first text, J would have a left letter (I) and D would have a right letter (F)

This will then give me a decoded message. The only problem is I don't know what method I would use to approach this.

Anyone have any ideas? I feel like I don't have enough knowledge to even know where to begin.

I have the message (MONCLET....) and key (JD IR BW....) set up. But the decoded message is using the message and the key to create one final message.

Reading lines using this:

```
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\assignment5\\data20.txt"));
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            key = f.readLine ();                      
            coded = f.readLine ();
            alpha = prepareKey (key);
            System.out.println (alpha);
            message = decode (coded, alpha);
            System.out.println (message);
        }
        f.close ();
```

Preparing key using

```
private static String prepareKey (String key)
{
return key;
}
```

Preparing decoded string using

```
private static String decode (String coded, String key)
{
return coded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you can try to put the letter in array form or lists (i.e. ArrayList), then you should try to loop around this values implementing your solution logic. 
Then you should build you answer in String variable.
So you can start with this to cast String into Char array

```
public class StringToCharJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "jtest";

        //string to char array
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(chars.length);

        //char at specific index
        char c = str.charAt(2);
        System.out.println(c);

        //Copy string characters to char array
        char[] chars1 = new char[7];
        str.getChars(0, 7, chars1, 0);
        System.out.println(chars1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok so It just prints 89 and then my string that I put in. How do I actually replace characters from the right and left of each group using the right and left characters of another string. If you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have parsed the input and it looks something like this:

```
    String message = "JD IR BW TQ DW SH UB XW AH NG AS XW CH UF BW FO DW SH UB BW TQ GW UH YG JV IE VM YE JD UO";
    String translations = "MONCLETABDFGHIJKPQRSUVWXYZ";
```

Then this is how you can decode the message:

```
    String decodedMessage = doDecode(message, translations);
    System.out.println(decodedMessage);
```

Where these are the supporting methods:

```
private String doDecode(String message, String translationsString) {
    Map<String, String> leftTranslations = buildTranslationTable(translationsString, -1);
    Map<String, String> rightTranslations = buildTranslationTable(translationsString, 1);

    String translation = "";
    String[] messagePairs = message.split(" ");
    for (String messagePair : messagePairs) {
        String messageLeft = Character.toString(messagePair.charAt(0));
        String messageRight = Character.toString(messagePair.charAt(1));
        String translationLeft = leftTranslations.get(messageLeft);
        String translationRight = rightTranslations.get(messageRight);
        translation += translationLeft + translationRight;
    }

    return translation;
}

private Map<String,String> buildTranslationTable(String translationsString, int offset) {
    Map<String,String> translations = new Hashtable<>();

    for (int i=0; i<translationsString.length(); i++) {
        if (               i >= 0 &&            i < translationsString.length() &&
                (i + offset) >= 0 && (i + offset) < translationsString.length() ) {
            String key = Character.toString(translationsString.charAt(i));
            String value = Character.toString(translationsString.charAt(i + offset));
            translations.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    return translations;
}
```